# HTTPS GET request not working with sim7000e lte module

Tags: https, putty, at-command

I am trying to make an HTTPS GET REQUEST to google, youtube, bing, baidu.com using sim7000E in PUTTY.
And it is not working every time I give a command

`AT+SHCONN`

I GET BACK

`ERROR`

or it gets hang.

THE AT commands I am using is from the official simcom docs

https://simcom.ee/documents/SIM7000x/SIM7000%20Series_HTTPS_Application%20Note_V1.00.pdf

from the page, no.13 to page 15 including PDN ACTIVATION COMMAND AND HTTPS COMMAND

and I have installed .cer files to customer folder of the sim7000E

[You can check that as well in this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KqpSg.png)

And another thing is for the website I have used .crt file I have skipped the code for converting.

I am facing the problem for so many days any help from StackOverflow community will be great.

Comment: This does not look like a [programming question](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: What error do you get when enabling more verbose errors with `AT+CMEE=2` ?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl the interaction with a modem is performed through AT commands, that is actually some sort of protocol. The commands are sent through a serial device, and this is often done with scripts and applications. Asking for guidance on them is really similar to asking help for understanding TCP protocol (that is considered in topic).

Comment: @Vansh please edit your question including ALL the commands you sent before `+SHCONN` and their responses as the ERROR you get will be likely dependent on some previous configuration error.

Comment: Of course I also agree with @hlovdal 's suggestion about `+CMEE` command.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the time on the device with
`AT+CCLK?` and make sure it's set to a time that the server certificate of the domain you're connecting to is valid for.

Make sure you have connected to the network with

`AT+CNACT=1,"your apn"` and received the `+APP PDP: ACTIVE` response

Also, make sure to tell the modem to accept all certs with

`AT+SHSSL=1,""`

And finally set the BODYLEN and HEADERLEN before attempting to connect

`AT+SHCONF="BODYLEN",1024`

`AT+SHCONF="HEADERLEN",350`

See [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/baconcheese113/1f0264727fce3fa51a5bb06fa031aed2) for more info